# Power BI with Angular4/5

Tags: angular, angular5, powerbi-embedded

How can I import PowerBI-JavaScript and it dependencies inside a Angular 4 application, and use it inside services and components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install from NPM:**

npm install --save powerbi-client

**than declare in your component like**

import * as pbi from 'powerbi-client';